# Main text inside the html code

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to get the main text of the html code.By main i mean - only the text that is not links or comments of images. For instance, lets say i want only the main article of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) website - How can i get only the beginning part, the History part the Markup part etc. Without See also or References.

**Questions**:

- Is there any "tags hierarchy" that will get me to the main article?
- If there is such hierarchy, does it suitable for all the html codes?or each one has a different way to get to the main article?

I tried this Xpath pattern but it gave me additional text and it doesnt work in all of the html codes: "//body/div/div"
I am not very familiar with HTML codes so I am kind of guessing the Xpath pattern. I know it is not very clear question but...Thanks :)

Comment: I think an all generic approach will be next to impossible since HTML documents can be VERY different. You will at least have to provide an excerpt of a typical representative to start with.

Comment: Maybee there is a very general aproximate pattern, which will be the closest thing to that?

Comment: There are no general approaches to determine "main" contents in HTML pages. Instead you should prepare particular XPaths for each web page, in your case. Or you need to use a kind of semantic interpreter of web page to find out "main" part.

Comment: I agree with the comments, what you want to do is simply not possible. It is like you want to get the main information out of a newspaper article: It involves a lot of context and is not possible using a simply query. How you do determine what is main text and what is just a footer or some other, less important content? However, in HTML5 there is a `role` attribute, which can point you to the correct element., However, next to no-one is using this, so it is not a very general approach

Comment: Perhaps when im using the same "kind" of html codes it is possible? For instance, maybee these kind of articles have the same html code style? - http://finance.yahoo.com/news/pfizer-mulls-100-billion-bid-104817209.html , http://finance.yahoo.com/news/wall-street-week-ahead-spring-232055540.html , http://finance.yahoo.com/news/gm-aims-boost-cadillac-sales-104044137.html

Comment: hmmm...maybee this pattern: "//body//p"? will this work?